# Mic signal bleeding into speakers

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, signal

So this is a very strange problem. Sometimes, pretty rarely whenever I am actively using my mic I can hear myself in the speakers repeat what I've said a couple of seconds ago. I've been trying for a long time to figure out what was the cause of that. I even ended up reinstalling Windows/sound drivers in hopes to fix it but it still happens sometimes.

It only happens on my newer PC and never happened on the old one. Could it because of a faulty onboard audio? From what I understand the wireless/USB headsets are not affected by the sound cards so it's probably not it. But I had this problem on 3 different wireless/USB headsets and have literally no idea what could be causing this problem.

I run Win10/Logitech G933 wireless at the moment. I used Corsair VOID both wired and wireless versions before and they both had this problem as well.

Comment: is it only repeated once - then it may be a Problem in Audio Routing eg. different tact setting for mic and other audio streams which are played together so that at least one of them probably the mic needs to be resampled to the same tact - or is it more in shape of an echo with a really rapid falling volume so you only think you hear it only once? if the last one is the case it maybe a normal feedback loop where your mic not only hears you but also whats coming out of your speaker.

Comment: It is repeated once from what I can gather without the volume falling. Sometimes it's a word or two, sometimes it's my own breathing but it happens. eg: when I was talking to a friend I said "yes, of course". Then I heard my own voice like 5 seconds later in my headset speakers saying the same thing. I was thinking it might be because of TS3 so I tried Skype. Same happened there and I moved to Discord. Didn't make any difference. 

Could you please explain the tact part? This is outside my area of expertise and I didn't really understand it

Comment: i can try to - this place here is to small to explain you the whole thing about sampling rates it selfs but i can give you the link to wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing) - now if you more or less understand this you may also understand that if one sound eg. ingame audio is lets say sampled at 96kHz and your mic is lets say sampled at 44kHz one of them needs to be resampled since one audiocard can only output one samplerate at a time - it can be that why those strange things come from resampling (why this can happen will exseed this space way to much)

Comment: Thanks. So different tacts can be the cause of my mic looping back into speaker signal? It is still really strange because I had 3 different headsets - Corsair VOID USB, Corsair VOID wireless and now Logitech G933 and it happens on each one of them randomly. They all have their own separate soundcards so my onboard sound card isn't even in use.

Also, wouldn't the loopback be constant? Why is it random like that? I'm just trying to understand how does it work.
edit: my speaker is sampled at 16bit 48000hz
mic is 16bit 44110hz

Comment: no - if it would be from speaker to mic it would be a normal audio feedback loop and more like a echo (but this normally only happens with monitor speakers not with headphones) - what i'm talking about happens inside the PC or in your case inside the Audio Hub from the Headphones - try to find a settings dialog for your Headphone mic looking somewhat like this http://www.qsl.net/dl4yhf/speclab/W7_Sound_Microphone_Properties.png were you can change the samplingrate of your mic to be the same as the other sound if you don't know what the other sounds use just try out different setting

Comment: OK, I changed my microphone's sample rate to the same one as my speakers. Still this is some really weird stuff because why isn't the issue more widespread? I'm pretty sure the default sample rates for mic and speakers are different for my headset. But it only happens to me though. Must be something inside my PC